# Missing date data when getting data from Google Analytic 4 (GA4) to create chart with granularity daily?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm getting started with Google Analytics 4, and I have a task is creating chart report with custom  dimensions. I have a problem when get data from API. It missing date data when getting data from GA4. I want to use this data to build a chart

```
const {
      propertyId,
      startDate,
      endDate,
    } = req.query;

    // Request report data.
    const analyticsDataClient = await getAnalyticsDataClient(getActiveShop(req));
    const response = await analyticsDataClient.runPivotReport({
      property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
      dimensions: [
        { name: "date" },
        { name: "CUSTOM_DIMENSION_EVENT" },
        { name: "CUSTOM_DIMENSION_EVENT" },
        { name: "CUSTOM_DIMENSION_EVENT" },
      ],
      metrics: [
        { name: "sessions" },
        { name: "activeUsers" },
        { name: "CUSTOM_METRIC_EVENT" },
        { name: "CUSTOM_METRIC_EVENT" },
      ],
      dateRanges: [{ startDate: 2022-12-06, endDate: 2023-01-03 }], // Dateranges
      pivots: [
        {
          fieldNames: ["date"],
          limit: 30,
        },
        {
          fieldNames: ["CUSTOM_DIMENSION_EVENT"],
          limit: 5,
        },
        {
          fieldNames: ["CUSTOM_DIMENSION_EVENT"],
          limit: 5,
        },
        {
          fieldNames: ["CUSTOM_DIMENSION_EVENT"],
          limit: 5,
        },
      ],

      dimensionFilter: {
        filter: {
          fieldName: "CUSTOM_METRIC_EVENT", // id
          stringFilter: {
            matchType: "EXACT",
            value: "CUSTOM_METRIC_EVENT_ID",
          },
        },
      },

      keepEmptyRows: true,
    });
```

response GA4 API

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "pivotHeaders": [
        {
          "pivotDimensionHeaders": [
            {
              "dimensionValues": [
                {
                  "value": "20221227", // return this date only
                  "oneValue": "value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "rowCount": 1
        },
        {
          "pivotDimensionHeaders": [
            {
              "dimensionValues": [
                {
                  "value": "885c7b0d-bc65-47be-b7df-871947bc5de4",
                  "oneValue": "value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "rowCount": 1
        },
        {
          "pivotDimensionHeaders": [
            {
              "dimensionValues": [
                {
                  "value": "New Page For Test GA4",
                  "oneValue": "value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "rowCount": 1
        },
        {
          "pivotDimensionHeaders": [
            {
              "dimensionValues": [
                {
                  "value": "index",
                  "oneValue": "value"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "rowCount": 1
        }
      ],
      "dimensionHeaders": [
        {
          "name": "date"
        },
        {
          "name": "customEvent:page_id"
        },
        {
          "name": "customEvent:page_name"
        },
        {
          "name": "customEvent:page_type"
        }
      ],
      "metricHeaders": [
        {
          "name": "sessions",
          "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "name": "activeUsers",
          "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "name": "customEvent:revenue",
          "type": "TYPE_CURRENCY"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        {
          "dimensionValues": [
            {
              "value": "20221227",
              "oneValue": "value"
            },
            {
              "value": "885c7b0d-bc65-47be-b7df-871947bc5de4",
              "oneValue": "value"
            },
            {
              "value": "New Page For Test GA4",
              "oneValue": "value"
            },
            {
              "value": "index",
              "oneValue": "value"
            }
          ],
          "metricValues": [
            {
              "value": "7",
              "oneValue": "value"
            },
            {
              "value": "7",
              "oneValue": "value"
            },
            {
              "value": "0",
              "oneValue": "value"
            },
            {
              "value": "8",
              "oneValue": "value"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "aggregates": [],
      "metadata": {
        "dataLossFromOtherRow": false,
        "schemaRestrictionResponse": {
          "activeMetricRestrictions": []
        },
        "_schemaRestrictionResponse": "schemaRestrictionResponse",
        "_currencyCode": "currencyCode",
        "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "_timeZone": "timeZone"
      },
      "propertyQuota": null,
      "kind": "analyticsData#runPivotReport"
    },
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

Although I set dateRanges `{ startDate: 2022-12-06, endDate: 2023-01-03 }` , it only returns `20221227` for me? What's problem here?

Answer (score 0):

If you check [runPivotReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runPivotReport) in the doucmentation you will find that the response body for a [RunPivotReportResponse](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/RunPivotReportResponse)

Does not contain dates, the api probably assumes you know what dates you requested.

```
{
  "pivotHeaders": [
    {
      object (PivotHeader)
    }
  ],
  "dimensionHeaders": [
    {
      object (DimensionHeader)
    }
  ],
  "metricHeaders": [
    {
      object (MetricHeader)
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      object (Row)
    }
  ],
  "aggregates": [
    {
      object (Row)
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    object (ResponseMetaData)
  },
  "propertyQuota": {
    object (PropertyQuota)
  },
  "kind": string
}
```

Comment: @DalmTo I confused about it, so what API can I use for create a chart

Comment: I wanna response have all date from date ranges. For example, dateRanges is from 2022-12-01 to 2022-12-31, it has 31 days, and the response return all data per day, like `{date: "2022-12-01", data: "VALUE_DATA", date: "2022-12-02", data: "VALUE_DATA" .... }` as expected

Comment: I would go with the same api just use [run report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runPivotReport).    Why exactly did you use pivotreport anyway?

Comment: I tried but it only return some dates for me, not all dates. I need data of all dates although value can be '0' or anything else

Comment: pivoreport is not mandatory, I'm going to find API which I can use for build chart, I also searched `cohort` API

Comment: That not how it works you will only get back data that exist the API isn't going to add 0 for you that your job.  Your not going to find an API that doesn't exist.   maybe you should create one